# Using raspberry pi to take wireless signal and send it out onboard nic

Tags: networking

I have a raspberry pi that I have a wireless usb adapter attached to and I would like to take the wifi signal I get from the wireless adapter and send it out of the onboard nic. Is this possible? If it is possible how would I go about doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! Have you tried anything out yet that hasn't worked? That would help us get a general idea of what to suggest and might save some time. Also, pop into the chat from time to time. We always love company!

Comment: Well TCP/IP routes packets to IP addresses. So if your target machine is on 192.168.0.50 then whatever you are sending from via WiFi needs to send it to that address. You bridge WiFi and LAN and make sure all your devices are in the same IP range and subnet. And the packets will reach your destination. How you intercept the packets on the destination is up to you or the software running there which is bound the listening Port.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn your Pi into a wireless accesspoint, you can follow this tutorial: http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview

Comment: That tutorial is the wrong way around, but if you skip to the `Configure Network Address Translation` section, and swap wlan0 and eth0, it should do the trick.